# ASP.NET Core 3.1 posting data to related tables(one to many) ending up with sqllite error 19 'Foreign key constraint failed

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

.NET Core and Entity Framework Core I have made progress in creating a one to many relationship with my tables. My Issue is creating a post action in my controller to add data to these tables via postman test right now I'm not even sure I am testing it right and could use a little guidance on navigating these issues.

my main entity model

```
public class Asset
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        // Foreign Key
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        //Navigation Property
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        // Foreign Key
        public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
        //Navigation Property
        public Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public string PurchasePlace { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public DateTime AcquiredDate { get; set; }
        public float PurchasePrice { get; set; } 
        public float CurrentValue { get; set; }
        // Foreign Key
        public int ConditionId { get; set; }
        //Navigation Property
        public Condition Condition { get; set; }
        // Foreign Key
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        //Navigation Property
        public Location Location { get; set; }
        public DateTime RetiredDate { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

my category model

```
public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
    }
```

my other models are similar to  the cateogry model
I then have setup DTO's Based on the asset model and cateogry model and using automapper to create the mappings

automapper helper

```
public AutoMapperProfiles()
        {
            CreateMap<Asset, AssetDto>().ReverseMap();
            CreateMap<AssetCreationDto, Asset>().ReverseMap();
        }
```

and my post action in my controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> PostAsset([FromBody] AssetCreationDto assetCreationDto)
        {
            try
            {
                var asset = _mapper.Map<Asset>(assetCreationDto);
                _context.Assets.Add(asset);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                var assetDto = _mapper.Map<AssetDto>(asset);

                return CreatedAtAction("GetAsset", new { assetDto.Id }, assetDto);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }

            return null;


        }
```

assetCreationDTO

```
public class AssetCreationDto
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public string PurchasePlace { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public DateTime AcquiredDate { get; set; }
        public float PurchasePrice { get; set; }
        public float CurrentValue { get; set; }
        public int ConditionId { get; set; }
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        public DateTime RetiredDate { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

What I am trying to do is add a cateogry to the asset aswell as the category table so that It can populate a category drop down and also be populated by a combobox entry I am not sure how to set this up same with location and manufacturer the condition will be pre populated and just fill in a drop down with it's data I am sure I can figure that out once I can get the others populating correctly

here is the postman test that Im testing with that is resulting in the sql error as I have said Im not sure I am doing it right though .

[image]

Any help to steer me in the right direction would be great If there is any further information needed let me know and ill be happy to provide it .

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue I was getting the error because there was no data in the database once I pre populated my tables and tested I got the correct result in postman. So the above code works as expected .